# Mainteance Mode Causes CSS to be removed

Tags: 7, theming

I am getting my site ready for an update, but whenever I put my site in maintenance mode, all it does is remove all the CSS and images from the site and just shows the content.

Does anybody know what is happening?

Comment: You might need to log out before it works.

Comment: Which theme are you using in maintenance mode? Does that theme has a `maintenance-page.tpl.php` (Drupal 7) or `maintenance-page.html.twig` (Drupal 8)?

Comment: It's Drupal 7. I am logged out, when I review the page I Just the top two header images and then the navi without any other support images or CSS. Site is hosted on Acquia.

Comment: Do you have a `maintenance-page` template?

Comment: I am not sure, I will have to check. But isn't there a default one that appears with you simply typing a message on the provided message box within the dashboard when your enabling maintenance mode.

Comment: Checked....it appears we have a custom template for our homepage, but not for our maintenance page, but we enabled the maintenance page previously without any problems. Wondering why it is acting the way it is now?

Comment: Does anonymous user have the permission "view site in maintenance mode"?

Answer (score 0):

Create a maintenance template file and place it in your theme folder. It's probably using a parent theme maintenance template or just the regular core one.